# Django ORM saving uploaded file without modelform

Tags: django, django-models

This is my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    certificate = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
```

I am trying to update the certificate when user upload the file in frontend.

doing it like this below:

```
def update(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
            profile.certificate = request.POST['certificate']
            profile.save()
        return render(request, 'dashboard/update.html')
    else:
        return redirect('user.login')
```

I see the field is populated but when I click on the file name on Django template, this is not showing, says page not found but I have another file field in the same model, which is not updated, it is working fine.

Can anyone help me to get it done? I am trying to uploaded file saved without modelfrom, not getting how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, files uploaded are accessible via `request.FILES`, not `request.POST`! So, it should be:

```py
profile.certificate = request.FILES['certificate']
```

Also, make sure in your template that you've got the following:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'your_url' %}">
    [...]
</form>
```

(note the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, without that files can not be uploaded).

If this does not work, please show us the template and the form used for that!